# How to access sobject name in lightning

Tags: lightning

I need to get the sobject's API name in the lightning JS controller, in the component side we need to specify `<aura:attribute name="sObjectName" type="String" />`, but to access in controller, can some one please say.
For `recordId`, we do this,

```
action.setParams({
    "accountId": component.get("v.recordId")
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement **force:hasSObjectName** in your component as below

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName" access="global" >
```

Then in your JS controller you can retrieve the name as below

```
var name = component.get("v.sObjectName"); // gives you the sObject name
var name = component.get("v.recordId"); // gives you the id of the sObject
```